# onClick not working after defining multiple onClick events

Tags: reactjs

I had an onClick event define which was working fine:

```
onClick={this.props.removeFunctionsData.bind(null,this.props.path,this.props.obj.data_type)}
```

Now I want to define two events on the same onClick. I tried doing this:

```
onClick={(e)=>{this._onClose(e);this.props.removeFunctionsData.bind(null,this.props.path,this.props.obj.data_type);}}
```

But in this case only *this._onClose(e)* works and not the original one. How can I fix this?

Comment: remove the bind and directly call the `removeFunctionsData` method, because bind returns a new function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Original answer** :

You can execute your function by adding `()` at the end :

```
onClick={
  (e)=>{
    this._onClose(e);
    this.props.removeFunctionsData.bind(null,this.props.path,this.props.obj.data_type)();
  }
}
```

**Edit** : as dschu commented, the above code is pretty bad, binding or using arrow function in the render method is a bad practice because it creates a new function each time.

- Binding your function is useless in this case because you pass `null` as first argument.
- To solve the arrow function performance issue in a generic way you have to bind your function in the constructor or declare an arrow method.

Here's a better code to do what you need :

```
Class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // your other class methods
  handleClick = (e) => {
    this._onClose(e);
    this.props.removeFunctionsData(this.props.path,this.props.obj.data_type);
  }
  render() {
    <div onClick={this.handleClick} />
  }
}
```

Comment: how can I use it inside the hook, I face the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your component, define a `handleClick` function, using the [ES6 arrow function syntax](https://medium.com/quick-code/react-quick-tip-use-class-properties-and-arrow-functions-to-avoid-binding-this-to-methods-29628aca2e25). This syntax doesn't create a new context, therefore you don't have to bind `this` inside the constructor or when calling it.

#### Here's an example using the info I've got from your post

```
class Example extends React.Component {
    handleClick = () => this.props.removeFunctionsData(this.props.path, this.props.obj.data_type);

    render() {
        return (
            <ComponentToClick onClick={this.handleClick} />
        )
    }
}
```